# CouchDB Join or suggestion for the following situation

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb

I have a DB with a list of documents which contains info of users, another database with documents for user logs.

In `SQL`, it could be simply to use `join`, but it seems like it is not possible to do it with just a simple query.

I have done some research that some suggestions shows:

> 1: to replicate the needed data to a database and then do the view, as the needing data are now in the same database.

And alternative suggestion was

> 2: to pull out the needed data from each database, and then run the query.

I guess, comparing between 1 and 2, it would be better to choose 1 as less data over `http`.

But regardless either 1 or 2, they are still not good enough as data duplications.

Is there any better suggestion someone could recommend?

Thanks

Example:

DB_USER.Doc_User_A : { userID:A, userName:Mr A, userEmail: A@A.com}

DB_LOG.Log_2013_11_11 : {userID:A, log:Hello}

expect to have sometime like [Mr A, 2013_11_11, Hello]

Comment: Can you share the scheme of the documents for the user and log? At least the relevant fields (the one you would use for "join" and those to project - desired result of the select).

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the user and log data inside the same document, as follow:

```
{id:1, user_id:123, type:'user', name:'maria'},
{id:2, user_id:123, type:'log', description:'test test test '},
{id:3, user_id:123, type:'log', description:'test1 test1 test1'},
{id:4, user_id:135, type:'user', name:'joão'},
{id:5, user_id:135, type:'log', description:'lalalalal lalallala '},
```

So, when you create you map reduce you can emit both doc's and query by user_id:

```
function(doc) {
  emit(doc.user_id, doc);
}
```

Then, with one request you can get all information that you need, with one request.

To request one type you need:

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc.type=='user'){
    emit(doc.user_id, doc);
  }
}
```